# Convert wchar_t* type to managed UTF-8 string

Tags: string, unicode, c++-cli, wchar-t

How can I convert `wchar_t*` type to a managed `UTF-8` string in C++/CLI?

Comment: Do you mean managed UTF-16 string? Because that's the encoding `System.String` uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean `System::String` by "managed UTF-8 string" (although managed strings are UTF16) use

```
String ^systemstring = gcnew String(YoutrWCharString);
```

For samples and details see [How to: Convert Between Various String Types on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235631%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).